# How can I bring a value to SharePoint Dialog to bind data?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dialog

How can I bring a value to SharePoint Dialog to bind data?
I call the dialog like this

```
<input type="button" value="<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Id"] %>"   onclick="javascript:Open()" />
```

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
    function Open() {

        var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/View.aspx") %>';
        OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(strPageURL, 650, 400, "Add Document Type");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

JS

```
function OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight, dialogTitle, dialogAllowMaximize, dialogShowClose) {

var options = {
    url: dialogUrl,
    allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
    showClose: dialogShowClose,
    width: dialogWidth,
    height: dialogHeight,
    title: dialogTitle,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback4)
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);}
```

I don't know how to bring the Id value to the View.aspx.

Then I can populate the data in view.aspx page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the ID as a query string parameter. That would make your url line look like this:

```
var strPageURL = "<%= String.Format("{0}?id={1}", 
                   ResolveClientUrl('~/View.aspx'), 
                   ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)['Id']) %>";
```

giving you a url that looks something like

```
mysite.com/View.aspx?id=12345
```

then on view.aspx you should be able to grab the query string 'id' key's value.

**update:**

if you then use this line like in your example:

```
OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(strPageURL, 650, 400, "Add Document Type");
```

you should be able to access the query string param on postBack:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
    // use the id here
}
```

Comment: var strPageURL ... should be in the GridView ?

Comment: Where should I put this **var strPageURL ...** ? in the GridView ? Sorry about my ignorance !!

Comment: All I did was add on the your example. Look at the 5th line of your second code snippet.

Comment: Since it is in the javascript, it will be difficult for me to pass the **((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)['Id'])** since it refers to each row. Can I write my server code in javascript ?

Comment: As far as I can tell it shouldn't be difficult. You're already using server side code with this ``<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/View.aspx") %>`` we're just making it longer.

Comment: I"ll add now. Thank you again .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I tried and solved.

it's in the gridview

```
<input type="button" value="<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DocTypeCode"] %>"  onclick="javascript:Open('<%#Eval("Id") %>')" />
```

it is the javascript

```
function Open(id) {
    var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/_layouts/RPSWA/Dialogs/DocTypeView.aspx?id=") %>' + id;
```